# Software to create windows partitions beyond maximum allowed

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

My OS is Win 7 Ultimate and have 3 partitions. Now, I would like to resize one partition and create one more. However, the partition manager in Windows 7 says that I already have the maximum allowed.

Are there any other software which allows me to create additional partitions beyond the maximum allowed by Win 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have as many partitions as you want - (you can't mount more than 26!), It sounds like you are creating the wrong sort.

You can only create 4 primary partitions (unsure why you are getting a message with 3 - are you counting the System and/or hidden ones?).

You can however create an extended partition, then create as many logical partitions inside of that.

If you are still having problems and/or the Windows Disk Management tool will not allow you to do it, I recommend that you take a look at [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: How to create an extended volume? I can't see any such option. http://oi52.tinypic.com/eqdzwp.jpg

Comment: @Ctroy - That green outer box shows an extended partition and the V drive is a logical partition inside of it. You have sort of got a weird order, if you use Gparted, you may be able to move that free space in the middle to the end, alternatively, it is awkward, but I would recommend  creating a new 20GB drive at the start of the unallocated 70GB, and move everything from the D drive to it, then delete the D drive and reassign the D letter to it, then try to do something similar with the V drive - see if you can offload the data somewhere and delete it, to recreate the extended in all that

Comment: space... there isn't really an easy solution...

Comment: I will try to use Gparted like you mentioned. I hope I don't lose my data. By the way, do you know any easy or simple way to get the drive data as an iso image? Or any other way to take backup easily? Thx for your help :)

Comment: By the way, just to be sure, isn't it possible to do the thing you using the partition manager that exists in windows 7?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be a need to use Gparted... Sorry I mentioned it - I only said it because it makes it possible to do multiple operations quick... but you can do everything you need in Windows. You shouldn't loose any data. As for backup, look for backup and restore in the search box of the start menu, you can do a complete pc image from there.... As I said, do it in little stages, but you need to get all the chunks of free space together! Are you using any of the V drive yet?

Comment: First of all, I am not able to create a simple volume in the unallocated space (because as you told 4 primary partitions already exist). The first partition cannot be deleted since it is a recovery partition. Now, I can't extend the partition which has the V drive in it. Not sure why, but I cant find the option to extend when I right click on it. How can I create an extended partition in C? It has my other OS which I don't use.

Comment: How much "stuff" do you have on both D and V at the moment?

Comment: Well, it took several hours, but I am able to organize all of my partitions.. Gparted worked great. Thanks for your help, Wil.